# Error during fetching big data using GridFS (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

When I'm trying to fetch file stored in MongoDB by GridFS (300mb) I'm getting error:

```
2014-07-16T22:50:10.201+0200 [conn1139] assertion 17144 Runner error: 
Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33563462 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes ns:myproject.export_data.chunks query:{ $query: { files_id: ObjectId('53c6e5485f00005f00c6bae6'), n: { $gte: 0, $lte: 1220 } }, $orderby: { n: 1 } }
```

I found something similar, but it's already fixed:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13611

I'm using MongoDB 2.6.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure which driver or driver version you are using, but it is clear that your implementation is issuing a "sort" and without an index you are blowing up the 32MB memory sort limit when pulling in chunks over a range.

Better driver implementations do not do this and rather "cycle" the chunks with individual queries. But the problem here is you collection is missing the index it needs, either by your own setup or by the driver implementation that created this collection.

It seems you have named your "root" space "export_data", so switch to the database containing the GridFS collections an issue the following:

```
db.export_data.chunks.ensureIndex( { files_id: 1, n: 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Or add something in your application code that does this to ensure the index exists.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug. It's clearly about `sort` as described in the error message, not about GridFS. Read this section about [sort limitation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#operations):

> MongoDB will only return sorted results on fields without an index if the sort operation uses less than 32 megabytes of memory.
>   Which means your sort aborts if it uses more than 32MB memory without index.

It will be better if you can post the statements you are executing.

Comment: I'm just getting data by gridfs (play):
val gfs = GridFS(db, DbConst.FILES_COLLECTION_NAME)
serve(gfs, gfs.find(BSONDocument("_id" -> new BSONObjectID(id))))